# Install a linux package on heroku

Tags: heroku

I need to install this package on heroku

```
apt-get install python3-tk
```

Can someone tell me how can I install this? I tried above command but I get this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-tk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Package 'python3-tk' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing apt packages requires sudo, which heroku doesn't allow you to do with slugs.
You can use this buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Or you can use the heroku docker support to push docker images. Those images won't allow you sudo either. But you will be able to use sudo when building them.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

If you still want to use buildpacks with docker and an easier way to install packages, there is also `heroku.yml` in developer preview:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-yml-build-manifest