# Send ICMP ping from python on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ping

I have a Django app running on Heroku. I want to ping an external website to see if it responds from my app. I have found multiple solutions locally, but none work on Heroku:

- Using `subprocess` doesn't work on Heroku, as  `No such file or directory: 'ping'` is returned when trying it from the Heroku app.
- There are many Python packages that execute a ping, but they all
  require root access, which isn't possible from Heroku.

I installed `iputils-ping` via the `https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/apt.tgz` buildpack, and confirmed I see it installed in the deploy logs:

```
remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_3%3a20190709-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote:  new Debian package, version 2.0.
remote:  size 40000 bytes: control archive=1204 bytes.
remote:      648 bytes,    18 lines      control              
remote:      334 bytes,     5 lines      md5sums              
remote:      693 bytes,    32 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
remote:  Package: iputils-ping
remote:  Source: iputils
remote:  Version: 3:20190709-3ubuntu1
remote:  Architecture: amd64
remote:  Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
remote:  Installed-Size: 106
```

I have an Aptfile inside my root folder:

```
In [4]: os.listdir()
Out[4]: 
['Aptfile',...]
```

and in that is one line:

`iputils-ping`.

I then try to run: `subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "2", url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)` but I get an error:

```
<ipython-input-5-f67d5e6c83d7> in <module>
----> 1 subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "2", url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    499         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
    500 
--> 501     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    502         try:
    503             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
    945                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    946 
--> 947             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    948                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    949                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1817                     if errno_num != 0:
   1818                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1819                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1820                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1821 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ping'
```

Comment: @Chris thanks, I installed that successfully ("remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_3%3a20190709-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb" in the build log), but I'm still getting "No such file or directory: 'ping'". Am I missing a step?

Comment: I believe it should just work. Are you using the `Aptfile` approach or the Docker container approach? Can you show the code you're using to run `ping` from Python? Please [edit] this info into your question.

Comment: Hrm... I might've found the problem. Can you try replacing `"ping"` in your `subprocess.run()` call with `".apt/bin/ping"` or `"/app/.apt/bin/ping"`? That's not a good solution, but if it works I'll write up a proper answer to explain what's happening and hopefully suggest a better one.

Comment: @Chris unfortunately not, got ```CompletedProcess(args=['/app/.apt/bin/ping', '-c', '2', 'google.com'], returncode=2, stdout='', stderr='/app/.apt/bin/ping: socket: Operation not permitted\n')``` for each of those

Comment: Well at least we've found the binary now. Based on this new output, I suspect you won't be able to send a ping from Heroku no matter what you do... it looks like dynos are configured to forbid this kind of network communication. As a final check, if you `heroku run bash` and then try to run `ping` interactively, do you get the same error?

Comment: I've reopened the question and I'm going to start putting together a more detailed answer about this. I think it's different enough from the duplicates that I found earlier.

Comment: (That is, if you run `.apt/bin/ping` or `/app/.apt/bin/ping` interactively. I'm pretty sure just running `ping` will give command not found as before.)

Comment: Those both gave "operation not permitted" as well

Comment: Yep, unfortunately I think you're out of luck. I've posted a detailed answer in case you want to dig in further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complex than it might appear on the surface. Unfortunately, it looks like it may not be possible.

### Install the ping command

My first suggestion is to install the `iputils-ping` package using [the Apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) and call that from your Python code. This is [a good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48896879/354577) [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63204090/354577) [for installing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55192742/354577) Ubuntu packages on your dyno, and it usually works.

### Command not found

Except in this case, `ping` won't be on the `PATH`, so simply running `ping` won't work.

This is because of how the Apt buildpack operates. Instead of simply `apt-get install`ing everything, [it pulls the `.deb` files down](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt/blob/0a778933873c3b4c4e5f046db41890ea609afb74/bin/compile#L83-L94) and [extracts them](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt/blob/0a778933873c3b4c4e5f046db41890ea609afb74/bin/compile#L100) to a special location: `$BUILD_DIR/.apt/`. It then [adds `$HOME/.apt/usr/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt/blob/0a778933873c3b4c4e5f046db41890ea609afb74/bin/compile#L106).

For most binaries, this will work fine. Except the `iputlis-ping` package (and the alternative `inetutils-ping` package) [put the `ping` binary in `/bin/`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/iputils-ping/filelist), not `/usr/bin/`.

On a regular Ubuntu machine, [`/bin` is simply a symlink to `/usr/bin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266517/12606) so either path will work, but the Apt buildpack doesn't have a link like that. `ping` is *only* available as `$HOME/.apt/bin/ping`, and the buildpack does *not* add `$HOME/.apt/bin` to the `PATH`.

So, you should be able to run it via that full path (`/app/.apt/bin/ping`). That's not ideal since it won't work locally, so modifying `PATH` may be the best solution.

I think that should be achievable by [adding a file like `.profile.d/000-ping.sh`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt/issues/29#issue-278620667) to your repository¹:

```bash
export PATH=/app/.apt/bin:$PATH
```

### ...except root

But even after jumping through the hoops of installing the package and finding the binary, it doesn't look like it will work. Dynos appear to have their networking sufficiently locked down so as to prevent outgoing pings.

```
/app/.apt/bin/ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

Given that, it's unlikely that you'll be able to send a ping no matter what approach you try.

---

¹A better solution would be to update the buildpack to include a symlink from `.apt/bin` to `.apt/usr/bin`, mimicking a real system. I may submit a pull request if I can verify that this works.